# Connecting to HIVE in Mapper with Kerberos security

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, kerberos, oozie

My goal is to run MapReduce with connection to Hive in Oozie workflow scheduler on secured cluster(kerberos) HDP2.3.

I'm able to connect to hive in beeline or when I run it as java app(yarn jar) with the following connection string:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://host:10000/;principal=hive/_HOST@REALM", "", "");
```

But when I run it in Mapper it's failed.

```
 ERROR [main] org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport: SASL negotiation failure
    javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
        at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:212)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.handleSaslStartMessage(TSaslClientTransport.java:94)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:253)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.open(TSaslClientTransport.java:37)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport$1.run(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:52)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport$1.run(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:49)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport.open(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:49)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:190)
        ...
Caused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getInstance(Krb5InitCredential.java:147)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:121)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getMechanismContext(Krb5MechFactory.java:187)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getMechanismContext(GSSManagerImpl.java:223)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:212)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:179)
        at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:193)
```

How to make it working in Mapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It work with hive delegation tokens:

1. oozie

   - add properties:

     ```
     hive2.server.principal=hive/_HOST@REALM
     hive2.jdbc.url=jdbc:hive2://{host}:10000/default
     ```
   - Set credentials to **hive2**
   - Mapper Example:

     ```
     public class HiveMapperExample extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

         @Override
         protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
             try {
                 Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
                 Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://{host}:10000/;auth=delegationToken", "", "");
                 Statement state = connect.createStatement();
                 ResultSet resultSet = state.executeQuery("select * from some_table");
                 while (resultSet.next()) {
                     ...
                 }
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 ...
             }
         }
      }
     ```
2. ToolRunner

   ```
   public class HiveTestApplication extends Configured implements Tool {

       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
           System.exit(ToolRunner.run(new HiveTestApplication(), args));
       }

       @Override
       public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
           Configuration conf = new Configuration();
           //set your conf
           Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);
           job.setMapperClass(HiveMapperExample.class);

           addHiveDelegationToken(job.getCredentials(), "jdbc:hive2://{host}:10000/", "hive/_HOST@REALM");

           job.waitForCompletion(true);

           return 0;
       }


       public void addHiveDelegationToken(Credentials creds, String url, String principal) throws Exception {
           Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");

           Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url + ";principal=" + principal);
           // get delegation token for the given proxy user
           String tokenStr = ((HiveConnection) con).getDelegationToken(UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser().getShortUserName(), principal);
           con.close();

           Token<DelegationTokenIdentifier> hive2Token = new Token<>();
           hive2Token.decodeFromUrlString(tokenStr);
           creds.addToken(new Text("hive.server2.delegation.token"), hive2Token);
           creds.addToken(new Text(HiveAuthFactory.HS2_CLIENT_TOKEN), hive2Token);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: What do you mean with "Set credentials to hive2" in the first step? How to do so? And where?

Comment: Okay, I think I found out what you meant; add both settings and the token for hive2 to the workflow as described here:
https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/DG_ActionAuthentication.html
- with that it started working for me.

Answer (score -1):

The error "Failed to find any Kerberos tgt" is quite straightforward. You need to get a kerberos ticket before connecting to Hive on the node the mapper is being executed.

Comment: How to do that? Could you give an example? I'm currently investigating delegation token - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1696

Comment: It isn't easy to do that at all if you try to do it. The code running in yarn has a security manager and a ton of other settings that prevent "just getting a tgt" which is trivial outside of a map reduce job but prevented in a map reduce job.